# Proving that a certain series converge if and only if the a_n converges

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

I need to prove the following statement:

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of real numbers.Prove that

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_{n}-a_{n+1})$

Converges iff $\{a_n\}$ converges. If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_{n}-a_{n+1})$  converges, what is the sum?

Well my problem is how to manipulate this information to get the proof, is not obvious to me, can you help please, I'm having some problems with this thing. Thank you in advance.  **I have edited the post**

Comment: Why don't you try to evaluate the sum $\sum_{n=1}^N (a_n-a_{n-1})$ explicitly. Try $N=2,3$ and find a pattern.

Comment: thank you for your help I really appreciate it :)

Comment: I am sorry is a_n+1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_{n}-a_{n-1})$ converges means the partial sum $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n (a_{k}-a_{k-1})$ converges to a finite limit.

Remark that $S_n = a_n - a_0$, so $S_n$ converges to a finite limit if and only if $a_n$ converges to a finite limit, i.e. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_{n}-a_{n-1}) = \lim_{n\to +\infty}a_n-a_0$

Comment: and with this you are proving both directions isnt?

Comment: @user162343 yes, it proves the "iff"

Comment: and can I say it like that or I have to write more things, is because I find it very simple. :)

Comment: @user162343 I think you can say like this, all the necessary arguments are already there

Comment: ok thank you @PetiteEtincelle then this completes the proof :)

Comment: @user162343 You are welcome:)

Comment: oh I forgot something the part of the sum you complete it with  ∑∞n=1(an−an−1)=limn→+∞an−a0 ?

Comment: @user162343 I mean once we know $a_n$ converges, we have the identity

Comment: oh yes but then it says If ∑∞n=1(an−an−1) converges, what is the sum?

Comment: @user162343 The infinite sum is equal to the limit of $a_n$ minus $a_0$

Comment: ok then all is there, thanks for your answer, I thought you didnt answer that, thanks :)

Comment: I am sorry, I have edited my post because it was (a_n-a_n+1)

Comment: @user162343 You can deal with it in exactly the same way. Or remark that your edition is just adding a minus sign before the sum, with an obvious index translation

Comment: ok then is telescopic to ?

Comment: @user162343 why not make a try by yourself? All the arguments are the same

Comment: good let me try it and then I post my answer for a verification :)

Answer (score 2):

The series $\sum_{n\ge1}(a_n-a_{n-1})$ is convergent iff the partial sum sequence

$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n (a_k-a_{k-1})$$
is convergent and by telescoping we get

$$S_n=a_n-a_0$$
so $S_n$ is convergent iff the sequence $(a_n)$ is convergent and in this case we have

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(a_n-a_{n-1})=\lim_{n\to\infty } S_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n-a_0$$

Comment: and with this you are proving both directions isnt?

Comment: Yes I think so.

Comment: jajajaaj why "I think so"?

Comment: I mean Yes I'm sure I proved both directions:-)

Comment: ok thank you a lot :)